# Need to improve "very awkward" Rx logic to combine different data sources

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

I recently had to complete a tech-test for a job application, the specification for which is [here](https://github.com/mylesbennett/reactive-mvp/blob/master/Android%20Tech%20Test%20-%20New.pdf). In their feedback, one of the things they didn't like was my Rx logic for Screen 2 - combining the information from three separate API calls. Their exact words were:

- For post details presenter very awkward Rx logic to combine different data sources. Would really help to have a use case instead.
- Knowledge of Rx operators lacking, often using awkward solutions

Below is the code to which they are referring:

```
apiService.getPost(view.postId)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .map { posts -> posts[0] }
    .flatMap { post ->
        Observable.zip<String, String, String, String, PostDetails>(
            Observable.just(post.title),
            Observable.just(post.body),
            apiService.getUser(post.userId).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).map { it[0].username },
            apiService.getComments(post.id).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).map { it.size.toString() },
            Function4 { title, body, name, comments -> PostDetails(title, body, name, comments) }
        )
    }
    .observeOn(view.scheduler)
    .subscribe { view.showDetails(it) }
```

Below are the Retrofit interfaces for some context:

```
@GET("posts") fun getPost(@Query("id") postId: Int?): Observable<List<Post>>
@GET("users") fun getUser(@Query("id") userId: Int?): Observable<List<User>>
@GET("comments") fun getComments(@Query("postId") postId: Int?): i Observable<List<Comment>>
```

Whilst I was writing it, I actually thought the code was as succinct as it could be under the circumstances. Looking at it again now, however, and given their comments I have to admit it looks a little verbose.

How could I improve it? Specifically, which operators would help to tidy this up?

Comment: I don't see any awkwardness in your solution, which is quite readable: get the post first so that the user id is accessible, then fire off the user details and comment details requests, after which combine everything into an object via `zip`. Some flow patterns can be achieved multiple ways: some are equivalent and some are more convoluted. If possible, ask them how their "non-awkward" solution looks like.

Comment: You can remove `Observable.just()` but I am not sure if that's what they were referring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider including [RxKotlin](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxKotlin); it has some nice zip syntax from `Observables` that doesn't require explicit type declarations or the ugly `Function4`. Also, you can make use of extension functions to make sure the code is as descriptive as possible, and more functions in general will help neatly factor the "middle" logic and nested observables. Eg:

```
fun updatePostView() =
    apiService.getPost(view.postId)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .map { it.first() }
        .createPostDetails()
        .observeOn(view.scheduler)
        .subscribeBy(
            onNext = { view.showDetails(it) },
            onError = { it.printStackTrace() }
        )

private fun Observable<out Post>.createPostDetails(): Observable<PostDetails> =
    flatMap { post ->
        Observables.zip(
            getPostTitle(post),
            getPostBody(post),
            getPostUser(post),
            getPostComments(post)
        ) { title, body, name, comments -> PostDetails(title, body, name, comments) }
    }

private fun getPostTitle(post: Post) =
    Observable.just(post.title)

private fun getPostBody(post: Post) =
    Observable.just(post.body)

private fun getPostUser(post: Post) =
    apiService.getUser(post.userId).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).map { it.first().username }

private fun getPostComments(post: Post) =
    apiService.getComments(post.id).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).map { it.size.toString() }
```

Sure it's more code, but it's nicer to read. Otherwise, it seems you have a pretty good grasp of Rx operators in general from what you've provided.

Comment: Thanks for this. I didn't receive a notification that you had posted so have only just seen your answer now. I'll need time to digest it though...